# Performance on PKs using int and char(32)

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, sqlite, primary-key

Does it make any difference performance wise to have a primary key of a database table (say Users with user_id being the PK), be an int or a char(32)?

I am wondering this for MySQL and SQLite.

The int would be an auto increment at 1,2,3,... and the char(32) would be a unique 32 alphanumeric characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An index is more efficient when the table itself is stored in index order, because then it is not necessary to do a secondary lookup in the index to find a record.
This is typically called "index-organized table" or "clustered index".

In SQLite, you must declare the PK as [INTEGER PRIMARY KEY](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid) to get a clustered index.

MySQL supports both data types for a [clustered index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-index-types.html); the only difference is that `char(32)` occupies more space, and this might require more I/O.

Answer (score 1):

first of all I am not sure for SQLite but for MySQL it is better to use `INT` over `CHAR(32)` as a PK. It has to do with how MySQL builds up the index for the columns, so integers are always better than strings for PK.

Another thing is that `CHAR(32)` consumes much more space (32 Bytes = 256 bit) where an `INT(10)` only is 32 Bit long. That means that the `CHAR(32)` fields has much more different keys than the `INT(10)` field.